# All variables get updated instead of just one in Ruby/Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've been testing a method I made in a Module in RSpec. When comparing the results I've realised that the variable from the spec that I pass to the method gets updated. Here is the method being tested

```
def self.location_compact(locations)
  # Find regions 
  regions = locations.select{|l| l.tag == 'Region'}
  # Go through region ids and delete locations with that region as a parent (over 5)
  regions.map(&:id).each do |region_id|
    if locations.count{|location| location.parent_id == region_id} >= 5
      locations.delete_if{|l| l.parent_id == region_id}
    end
  end

  locations.map(&:name).map {|l| l.split.map(&:capitalize)*' '}.map { |e| "#{e}" }
end
```

And here is the spec:

```
let (:regions) { Office.where(tag: 'Region').sample(2) }
let (:locations) { Office.where(tag: 'MC', parent_id: regions.map(&:id)).sample(9) + regions }

context ".location_compact" do
  it "should delete locations that count more than 5 for region" do
    result = GIS::GetResponse.location_compact(locations)
    expect(result).to eq(locations.map(&:name).map {|l| l.split.map(&:capitalize)*' '}.map { |e| "#{e}" })
    expect(result.size).to eq(6)
  end
end
```

I want only the **result** to contain the updated array, instead **locations** also gets updated for some reason. I thought that variables in a method are isolated, instead it seems like its updating the memory location itself. Copying locations to another varible updates both of them... Is that I always assumed wrong and that's how Ruby works or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `delete_if` is mutating the array.  If you want to exclude those results, perhaps look into `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things in ruby are passed by reference, not copy. Array is certainly one of such things. So if you don't want it changed, either `dup` it or don't use destructive methods on it (your `delete_if` there).